# How to optimise the structure of odoo addon project?

Tags: python, odoo

I'm using odoo9.0 to develop my crm project.
Currently I put all of my logic code in models, but some business logic is complicated. For example, In model A I need to read data from model B,C and D, and write result data to model E. My problem is that the model A is getting bigger and bigger and becoming unmanageable. I want to split the model into smaller part. 
Can anyone give me some advice?